# Disable preview layer when recording on camera

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using https://github.com/chroman/HeartBeats to draw heartbeat's linechart. But, i want to remove preview layer (or disable it) and only display "linechart" on my own UIView, but i dont know where to edit.

[image]

im a beginer at iOS-dev, pls cmt if you know. thank you.

edit 1: i think `CALayer` is my issue. (on `viewDidLoad`):

```
imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
imageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];

[self setupAVCapture];
```

edit 2: note: red backgroud is your finger when place on it. if not, it will show what camera currently recording.

Comment: means you do not want red background ? add your relevant code in question!

Comment: Stop calling the [self setupAVCapture] in viewDidload.

Comment: yes, no red background, only display chart in my custom view. you can see codes in link above sir.

Comment: you should post code in question!!

Comment: thats just AVCaptureSession's setup function. i think its not relate with my problem.

Comment: i added codes, is that my problem?. pls help.

Comment: If you are thinking CALayer is your issue stop that line using comment and run again.

Comment: i tried many times, app will display "black screen" all the times. i think preview layer and  linechart come with together. But dont know how to solve it.

Comment: what you want instead of that red background ? transparent color or any other color ??

Comment: red background is your finger place on camera. if not, that layer look like preview layer (view with camera is recording). i want that white linechart run on black-view (my custom UIView).

Answer (score 0):

try to set background color as clear color or black color to your `layer` something like,

```
imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

or

```
imageLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: its still run normally. no differences. :(